# Como evitar o navegador padrão do aparelho mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo um captive portal para redes WiFi, onde o cliente se conecta e é automaticamente redirecionado para o portal web.

Gostaria de saber se é possível incluir um redirecionamento na pagina, para que ao invés de usar o navegador do SO do Smartphone, quando o mesmo for aberto automaticamente, a pagina redirecione para outro navegador como o safari ou o Chrome. Em especial o Safari, pois no IOS é onde tenho mais problemas.

Obrigado

Comment: Se entendi bem, você quer ter um redirecionamento especifico pro Google Crome? Independente do navegador Padrão?

Comment: Melhor seria consertar o portal para funcionar com qualquer browser. Inclusive pelo fato de o HSTS estar sendo adotado cada vez mais e mais, então a interceptação de coisas HTTPS de sites conhecidos vai passar a ser problema em todos os browsers com o tempo.

Comment: O portal em geral esta funcional. Mas quando utilizo o navegador integrado do SO de um smartphone, a autenticação com o google e facebook falham, pois quando a pagina de autenticação das redes sociais abrem neste navegador em especifico, ela acaba sendo aberta na mesma pagina do portal, e quando o processo termina, ele não consegue retornar para a pagina anterior.

Quando utilizado em qualquer outro navegar instalado, o processo ocorre normalmente, sendo que ao usar a rede social para autenticar, a pagina e aberta em uma nova aba para efetuar o login e coletar os dados.

Comment: Não sei se estou sendo muito claro, mas a intenção era só evitar esse navegador mesmo.